# How do download blob file into pdf format react JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Blob file coming from API (we are using promise fetching API) in react I am unable download and view the document.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var blobPDF = new Blob([ doc.output(docBlob) ], { type: 'application/pdf' });
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blobPDF);
blobUrl.save ('file.pdf')
```

Comment: `blobUrl.save()`??? If `URL.createObjectURL` is the native one, `blobUrl` is a string.